# Convert a list of KeyEvent objects to a string

Tags: android

I am working on an app which needs to be able to use external USB or Bluetooth keyboard wedges. I then capture the KeyEvents and cache them as needed (starting/end sentinels).

So at this point I have lists of KeyEvents that I need to turn into strings.

So I need to convert these ordered KeyEvents into a correct string.

```
List<KeyEvent> events = new ArrayList<KeyEvent>();
String eventString = eventsToString(events); //??????
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much research, this is what I came up with. I used a `KeyListener` which accepts key events. It then appends to an `Editable` based on the key events (considers shifts, etc). The code below will simply echo the growing String as the key events come in.

```
KeyListener tkl = new TextKeyListener(Capitalize.NONE, false);
Editable et = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("");

View.OnKeyListener key = new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            tkl.onKeyDown(null, et, keyCode, event);
        else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
            tkl.onKeyUp(null, et, keyCode, event);
        else
            tkl.onKeyOther(null, et, event); //NOTE: My devices never used KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE so I don't know if it should get fired here or with the key down event.

        Log.i(("Test: " + et.toString());
    }
};

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (key.onKey(null, event.getKeyCode(), event))
        return true;
    else
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using getDisplayLabel() for every event? Something like:

```
List<KeyEvent> events = new ArrayList<KeyEvent>();
StringBuilder strEvents = new StringBuilder();
for (KeyEvent k : events) {
    strEvents.append(k.getDisplayLabel())
    strEvents.append(",");
}

String eventString = etrEvents.toString();
```

Comment: I haven't actually tried this but I know it won't solve my problem. For instance If the user keyboard wedge typed a capitol 'A' your solution would show `LEFT_SHIFT_KEY,a` (or something like that). The problem is I want 'A' rather than 'a'. So it must account for special keys, etc.

Comment: So I tried it. It works but only partially. So getDisplayLabel() is getting the capitol letters correctly, but it won't get me '$' instead of '4'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Building on vaimvolk loop only using getUnicodeChar() ?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getUnicodeChar()

Comment: Same issue. The event for `$` is coming in and looks EXACTLY like it is for `4`. I'm getting three events. I'll add to my post to describe it a little better.

Comment: You should get multiple events (UP/DOWN and shift presses) but one of them should translate using the getUnicodeChar() to $ (specifically I think the "4 Down" event. You can follow how the keyCode with the metastate is converted here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/view/KeyEvent.java#KeyEvent.getUnicodeChar%28%29